# Excel - comparison of text between two columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, comparison

How do I compare two or more columns in an Excel worksheet to identify the difference. The comparison of two columns is related to text and not the numbers. Please advise.

Comment: Hi @flower2303 and welcome to SuperUser. Can you give us more details? Someone could help you much better if they had an example of your data and the sort of result you are hoping for.

Answer (score 1):

A very similar question here that should answer your question. It may take a little modification for multiple cells, but it should meet your needs.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14918931/comparing-two-text-cells-and-show-the-differnce-in-third-column-in-excel-sheet-2

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can get the actual substring of either cell as a result to see what is the differentiating portion but I would probably simply throw a column off to the side and use a statement like the following to get a Boolean value in response to two of the columns, then sort the table or filter it to then start looking at what might be another step in filtering.

```
=IF(A2=B2,TRUE)
```

For some of these comparison tasks I also use a program called WinMerge, awesome stuff there for comparing data. I usually create two text files and compare the content between each other.